# How to show div upon clicking drop down box

Tags: jquery

I have a drop down box with yes and no values. By default it's set to 'No' however when we select the value of yes another div should appear. Please help

Comment: your current html would be helpful.

Comment: would help if he accepted an answer to any of his previous questions too...

Comment: oh wow, 12 questions with none marked as an answer.  that's pretty bad. i didn't notice that before i spent 30 seconds writing my answer. damn. that's 30 seconds of my life i'll never get back :(

Comment: don't worry about it, you can claim the moral highground ;)

Comment: Where did @Hooray Im Helping's brilliant answer go? :)

Comment: @sagarmatha - although not a "strict" requirement, it is common to accept answers (click check mark on correct one) to accept answers to questions.  After 12 questions, I would expect "some" to have been answered to your satisfaction - thus you motivate folks to help you as the reputation gained is a "small" part of the reward you give to people who assist you.

Comment: @sagarmatha - in review of all your questions, I see you rarely include markup or code.  You can do that in your question, then hightlight it and click the 010101 button to show it as code or markup.  This practice will greatly assist and speed response to your questions (include what you have tried or markup for instance).

Comment: BTW: Why use a `<select>` for a boolean choice; the `<input type="checkbox" />` is designed to serve this exact purpose.

Comment: @jensgram it may have been flagged for having inappropriate language?  or maybe he just deleted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#IdOfYourDropDown').change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'Yes'){
        $('#IdOfYourDiv').show();
    }
    else{
        $('#IdOfYourDiv').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: and without jquery? :P

I'd type out an answer but I don't think the asker will accept any answer anyway

Comment: @Litso: I guess the 'without jQuery' has like no interesst to the OP, only tagging `jQuery`.

Comment: the question was tagged jQuery... so i gave a jQuery answer :)

Comment: @jAndy haha, didn't notice that. Sorry :P

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#my_dropdown_id').bind('change', function(){
   switch($(this).val().toLowerCase()){
      case 'yes':{
          $('#my_show_id').show();
          break;
      }
      case 'no':{
          $('#my_show_id').hide();
          break;
      }
   }
});
```

You can extend that `switch statement` with any other value you might want to test for.